# Why can not I create tcp socket from Android device to PC

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, wifi

I'm trying to connect my Android app to desktop server. The problem is when I try to create LAN via portable Wi-Fi hotspot on my smartphone everything works fine, but when I connect PC and phone to the router I have TimeOutException creating a socket in Android app. On the other hand, when I connect desktop client to desktop server via router it works fine too, so the problem occures only when I try to connect mobile client to desktop server via router.

Client code (Java):

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 1000); // TimeOutException
```

Server code (C++/Qt):

```
QTcpServer m_tcp_server;
// ...
m_tcp_server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, m_port);
```

ip address and port are right (100%)

UPD:

Thank you, guys.

It was just a router problem. I tested in on the another one and there is no problem

Comment: `I have TimeOutException creating a socket in`. No your socket is created fine. But the socket cannot connect to a server. Please tell which ip's you use.

Comment: I use my PC's ip which I get using ipconfig (192.168.0.29 if needed)

Comment: Check or switch off the firewall

Comment: Which port number?

Comment: I have no firewall on my comp, brandmauer is off and firewall on router is off too.

Comment: i tried different: 15635, 50000, 1000, 80, 1234 etc.

Comment: `QHostAddress::Any`. Try with ip of your computer.

Comment: maybe use a packet sniffer on your desktop (something like wireshark) , to make sure that you are receiving any packet from your phone (specifically look at the SYN packet)

Answer (score 0):

try check which ip you have assigned on android pohone and if you have route to the destination server ip.

Is possilbe you get different ip on wifi and different ip by cable.

Also you can try an android net tool to try connect to the server.

Comment: I have pinged PC from Android and Android from PC. Ping works fine. I have also scanned PC's ports using Network Discovery (Android) and the port of the server was not found. When I tried to scan ports via nmap (WIndows), it said that this port is filtered, the reason is no-response, but desktop client works

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, In my case i created server socket with wrong ip address.
Hotspot network band is 192.168.43.1~255

You need to create server socket with ip address that hotspot dhcp made like 192.168.43.11

I had wrongfully made server socket with ip 192.168.0.22, this is wrong.

And your android app should open client socket with it.